# Emails to Google Groups email address aren't working

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-groups

When I send an email to the an email address in Google Groups, I get the following error from

> **Mail Delivery Subsystem** mailer-daemon@googlemail.com
>
> We're writing to let you know that the group you tried to contact (***) may not exist, or you may not have permission to post messages to the group. A few more details on why you weren't able to post:
>
> - You might have spelled or formatted the group name incorrectly.
> - The owner of the group may have removed this group.
> - You may need to join the group before receiving permission to post.
> - This group may not be open to posting.
>
> If you have questions related to this or any other Google Group, visit the Help Center at https://support.google.com/a/thisdot.co/bin/topic.py?topic=25838.

The address is setup to forward to group members immediately, but it doesn't seem to be getting through in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps someone, if you don't see the "**Who can post -> Anyone on the web**"
You need to enable emails outside of the organization in
**Apps>Google Workspace>Groups for Business>Sharing settings**
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe Google doesn't post this within the group settings itself, something like "FYI: If your admin doesn't enable external emails, this won't work" near the external settings.. frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Emails to the group email address are inserted as and considered "posts" into the group thread.

If people outside the organization need to be able to send emails, you'll need to grant public access to be able to post to the group

1. Go to Group Settings > General

   [image: Group Settings]
2. Go to "Who can post" and set to "Anyone on the Web"

   [image: Who can post]

Comment: Is this no longer possible? My "Who can post" row ends at "Entire organization", there is no option for "Anyone on the web".

Comment: @stevex See [jekcom's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155211/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by creating the Group directly through Google Groups and not on the Workspace Admin site.

I was affected by [stevex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148192/emails-to-google-groups-email-address-arent-working#comment138543_148193)'s comment and wasn't able to set my Admin site created group of who can post to "Anyone on the Web".

The following should get it working:

1. Create a new group

   [image: Create a new group]
2. Set "Who can post" to "Anyone on the web"

   [image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please bear in mind that comments are not permanent. I.E. besides including the link you might want to quote the comment in case that it is no longer available later. P.S. Have you seen [jekcom's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155211/88163)?

Answer (score 0):

OK heres the fix>>

the admin must log on to the admin console: https://admin/google.com/

**Click>>**
*Groups
*Find the group in question
*Access settings
*Access type
*change "who can post" to "external"

Not sure why the admin cant handle this from the group settings page but nevertheless this will fix it.